# Javascript custom exception handling?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, exception

In Python there's a good, if lesser-used pattern that you can follow. Say you've just developed this neat Frobnosticator library. You might do something like this:

**exc.py**

```
class FrobnosticatorError(Exception): pass
class FrobnosticateConfigNotFoundError(FrobnosticatorError, FileNotFoundError): pass
...  # whatever other kinds of errors you want.
```

What this allows you to do is wrap your entire application in something like this:

```
try:
    do_all_the_things()
except FrobnosticatorError:
    print('Oh noes! We forgot to catch an error somewhere!')
except:
    print("Ugh. Something broke, but at least it wasn't something we threw!")
```

Right now I'm working on a node+coffeescript app that's both server and client side code. Unfortunately we're a bit legacy, running Node `v6.4.0` and Coffescript v1, if that makes a difference.

I would love to use this kind of pattern within our code - it would make a lot of things a lot cleaner.

I've searched for several different things like `javascript custom exception handling`, but I haven't found any good examples of people doing this.

I was picturing making something like a `lib/client/Exceptions.coffee` that housed all of these exceptions that we would then use throughout our codebase.

Does this seem like a reasonable plan, or is this a terrible thing to do in Javascript? Is there a better way to design our app so that we can specifically tell which errors came from our code, and which errors came from other libraries that we're using?

Comment: JavaScript has exceptions, the same as Python. You can use them in the same way.

Comment: I suppose you want this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: What I understood that you need to handle the exception based on its type. If I have a right understanding of your question [this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-error) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom error class extending the error:

```
class CustomError extends Error { /*...*/ }
```

You can basically throw everything in javascript, but with the error class you get stack traces:

```
throw "something"; // no stacktrace :(
throw new CustomError(""); // stack trace and type :)
```

When catching you can `switch` based on the errors constructor:

```
 try {
  //...
 } catch(error) {
   switch(error.constructor) {
    case CustomError:
    //...
    break;
  }
}
```

> Is there a better way to design our app so that we can specifically tell which errors came from our code, and which errors came from other libraries that we're using?

To just distuinguish them you could just set a property on the custom errors:

```
CustomError.protototype.custom = true;
```

Then its as easy as:

```
 catch(error) {
   if(error.custom) { /*...*/ } else { /*...*/ }
}
```

Comment: would it make more sense to use the constructor, or `instanceof`?

Comment: @wayneWerner doesnt matter, but `if(error instanceof CustomError) { ... } else if(error instanceof OtherError) { ... }` is a bit more repetetive

Comment: I think the point of the question is defining a hierarchy of error classes, and then catching a superclass. That needs to use `instanceof`, since `error.constructor` will be the leaf class.

Comment: @barmar that would be another way of solving this.